# Hosted Laravel 5.4 App shows "View [path.to.viewfile] not found."

Tags: php, laravel, view, host, file-not-found

I have tried hosting my Laravel app in Godaddy. The homepage works well as well as the log ins and dashboard after logging in. But the other views return a InvalidArgumentException in FileViewFinder.php line 137: "View [path.to.viewfile] not found.

I'm returning the view from the controller with `return view::make('path.to.viewfile')`

It works well on my localhost using XAMPP. Does anybody know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked filenames and permission? file names are case sensitive in Linux (your hosting provider uses it)

Comment: Cool, glad to help, also you should mark the answer that helped you as correct one.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change directory permissions at your server. Directories and files within the `storage` and the `bootstrap/cache` directories should be writable (e.g. chmod 777)