# Laravel Godaddy hosting: View not Found [Works locally]

Tags: php, laravel, view, hosting

I am trying to deploy a Laravel app onto godaddy shared hosting. And have tried several solutions mentioned on this site and others, such as:

-[Hosted Laravel 5.4 App shows "View [path.to.viewfile] not found."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42332652/hosted-laravel-5-4-app-shows-view-path-to-viewfile-not-found)

-[View [auth.login] not found at Shared Hosting Godaddy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49490698/view-auth-login-not-found-at-shared-hosting-godaddy)

However, my views still cannot be found, for some unknown reason that I cannot tell. I have tried the solutions mentioned here, but to no avail.

I checked the spelling of the views since Linux server is case sensitive.

the specific error can be viewed at : auctionSalvages.com

but in short::: `View [simpleComponents.HeaderComponents.MainHeader] not found. (View: /home/hostname/AutoShop/resources/views/layouts/main.blade.php)`

I have now successfully executed the following php artisan commands: clear-compiled,cache:clear,config:clear,route:clear and view:clear on the server through ssh.

but my view still returns above error..

any more ideas???

Comment: You should really provide links to the solutions you've tried and explain why they did not achieve your desired result.

Comment: solutions do not work

Comment: My first thought (as you mentioned case sensitivity) is permissions.  That is if you are sure the path is correct.  What I do and it sounds a bit stupid is I copy the actual path, then the error path and put them next to each other in a text editor and compare them, (but My spelling is terrible, blame my dyslexia for it).  If everything else is the same then the environment is usually to blame.

Comment: Same,  actually when I am using views I copy file name... As far as permissions go.. Which file would I have to change the permissions on... because I just changed the  [simpleComponents.HeaderComponents.MainHeader]  persmissions still getting error

Comment: hmm yeah I mentioned that......

Answer (score 0):

This may be a few years too late but here a few things you need to consider if this happened.

- Make sure that all the files in the **Public** folder of your app is copied into the **public_html** folder of your godaddy hosting site.  Make sure that the **Settings** in your cPanel File Manager (which is generally at the upper right corner) that **Show Hidden Files (dotfiles)** is checked.
- Make sure the you have the **.htaccess** file in your **public_html** folder with the correct permissions.

Typically, when you transfer files into your hosting site, you do so by uploading a zip file and then extracting the zip file in the root directory of your site.

And then, when you copy the files from the **Public** folder of your app, you generally just **Select All > Copy > Select *public_html***

However, sometimes, the files in your Public folder are hidden so you have to set the settings to Show Hidden File (dotfiles) to checked.